# Title page not centered

Tags: memoir, titles

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\title{Title} 

\author{Name}

\date{\today} 
\newcommand{\institution}{University\xspace}

\newcommand{\department}{Department\xspace} 

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{}\\[.5cm]
\institution\\ 
\emph{\department}\\[.2cm] 
Bachelorarbeit 
\par
\hrulefill
\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
Gutachter:\\
\textbf{Name}\\[.3cm] 
Betreuer:\\
\textbf{Name}\\[.3cm] 
\end{flushleft}
\vfill}
\preauthor{\begin{flushright}Bachelorarbeit von:\\\bfseries} 
\postauthor{\end{flushright}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle 
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

On the basis of the memoir class and [Maggi Memoir Thesis](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/maggi-memoir-thesis) I tried to begin formatting my thesis. However the title page is not centered but I would like it to.

I would like to remove the right box only for the title page so that it is not only centered inside the textarea but for the whole sheet of paper.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1) Please remove `\input{Intro.tex}` as we do not have it and it is irrelevant to this question. (2) Please explain what is wrong here.  Parts of this is centered others are not. What exactly do you want? BTW: I tend to code the entire title page by hand inside the `titlingpage` env instead of using `\maketitle`.

Comment: do you mean vertically or horizontally centered? Note that text might be centered regarding the `textarea` (what happens with `\begin{center}` or `\centering`), but not regarding the sheet of paper. Cf. e.g. the [canons of page construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction) (where page border are shown in black, and text area borders in red). You can check this by showing borders of the text area using `\usepackage{showframe}`...

Comment: @ebo Exactly I would like the title page to be centered with respect to sheet of paper. I will check the '\usepackage{showframe}' package. daleif I removed the tex and tried to explain better.

Comment: @idkfa what *should* ("theoretically") be good, is sometimes not the best solution. Let me explain: even for books, if you look closely, the text is not centered regarding the sheet of paper - neither vertically, nor horizontally ([example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Camus23.jpg/220px-Camus23.jpg)). Because it *should* look better this way - your opinion may vary, though. Regarding your problem, if you *really* want it "paper-centered", you should locally redefine the text area (see e.g. the [`typearea`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/typearea) package therefor).

Comment: @idkfa remember the @ if you want to ping. See `\calccentering` in the memoir manual, I tend to use it with a double `adjustwith` inside `titlingpage`, the outer to center with respect to the paper, the inner to change the margins of the titlepage (often to make it wider than the text with of the doc).

Comment: The titlepage is not the cover. It is (one of) the first pages after flipping over the cover. The titlepage shares the same text block as the rest of the document. It is fine as it currently is. When you center the content on the page, the titlepage will look completely of when the report is bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example of how I normally center a title page in a memoir doc. The margins in this example are quite large, to better show the effect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

% just an example
\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{8cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagestyle{showlocs}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
  \calccentering\unitlength % ok to mess with unitlength inside a group

  \begin{adjustwidth}{\unitlength}{-\unitlength}
    \kant[1]

    \bigskip

    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
      \kant[2]
    \end{adjustwidth}

  \end{adjustwidth}

\end{titlingpage}

 \kant

\end{document}
```

A few pages from the example

[image]

[image]