# Memoir: Centering a page title after changing the size via `size10.clo`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, fontsize, changepage

I'm designing the title page of a `memoir` document. My document is using 12pt font, and I'm using some title templates/macros that uses internally `\Large`, `\Small` and that expect my page title to be in 10 pts. Since I don't want to change these commands to absolute font size, I instead loaded `size10.clo` to switch back temporarily to 10pts as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601279/font-size-small-tiny-relative-to-the-current-font-size?noredirect=1#comment1508025_601279). I also saw [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338445/title-page-not-centered) that I can center my page title using `adjustwidth`. But unfortunately, when I combine both of these solution, my title is not anymore centered:

[image]

Any idea how I could center my title back while keeping `\Large` commands relative to the 10pts font?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
{
  \makeatletter\let\newcommand\renewcommand\input{size10.clo}

  \begin{titlingpage}
    \calccentering{\unitlength}
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{\unitlength}{-\unitlength}

      \begin{center}
        \rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}\\[\baselineskip]
        \Large Hello
        \rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}\\[\baselineskip]
      \end{center}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
  \end{titlingpage}
}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: although it may work in some cases the `size??.clo` files were never intended to be used locally or with other classes. I don't understand the use case here. `\Large` in size10.clo is 14pt which is `\large` at 12pt, so why not use `\large` ?

Comment: loading size10 locally will give local (essentially, wrong) values for all kinds of length including `\textwidth`, `\oddsidemargin` etc It does far more than just set the size used for `\Large`.

Comment: I would not even use `\Large` if you have specific size requirements for the title page, i'd use `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont` directly. This is just a mess.